# Como colocar InterstitialAD no aplicativo?

Tags: android

Como coloco aquele anúncio que ocupa a tela inteira no meu aplicativo , e só é fechado quando a pessoa clicar no X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anúncios de tela cheia, chamados de  [Anúncios intersticiais](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial) cobre toda tela da aplicação, como um modo *FullScreen*. Veja abaixo como é indicado e descrito na [própria documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial):

Primeiro deve-se instanciar um objeto InterstitialAd

```
...
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
requestNewInterstitial();
...
```

No ação do botão você deve verificar seu ad foi carregado usando isLoad(). Veja:

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
     mInterstitialAd.show();
} else {
     beginPlayingGame();
}
```

Veja o código completo de como deve ficar sua *main*:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    Button mNewGameButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNewGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame_button);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

        // aqui o seu adUnitId 
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("seu adUnitID aqui");

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
                beginPlayingGame();
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();

        mNewGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    beginPlayingGame();
                }
            }
        });

        beginPlayingGame();
    }

    private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                  .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                  .build();

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    private void beginPlayingGame() {
        // Play for a while, then display the New Game Button
    }
}
```